# query enterprise architect database

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to query the EA database in order to discover the visibility status of a class attribute.
I've been snooping around but could not find the table where this information is stored.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of inconsistent naming in EA. The property that's displayed as the attribute's Scope in the GUI is referred to as `Attribute.Visibility` in the API, and stored in `t_attribute.Scope` in the database.

Similarly, the same property of an element is displayed as Scope in the GUI, referred to as `Element.Visibility` in the API and stored in `t_object.Scope` in the database. There is a column `t_object.Visibility`, but it appears to be unused.

Comment: tnks for your help. I have a class used in diagrams A and B. The class has attributes a, b and c. In diagram A I use the feature visibility option to make attributes A.a and A.c visible. In diagram B, B.a and B.b. I need to query the database and discover what is visible in each diagram. With the info you provided I could not get there. Im I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it. Visibility of individual attributes it's actually in t_diagram.StyleEx